# Version control system that can handle both big file and cross-platform file names

Tags: windows, osx, cross-platform, version-control

I'm in a small company that develop audio software, and we have been seeking for a proper VCS software for pretty long times. We have two requirements:

1. Able to handle binary files. We have many audio files and pictures to be version controlled, and some of them could be rather large.
2. Able to handle cross-platform non-ASCII file names, as we are in China, and work on both Windows and Mac.

We have already tried those VCS:

- **Plastic** - what we are currently using - has many other problems;
- **Git** and **Mercurial** both can't do #2, and somebody told **Bazaar** has same issue;
- **Perforce** is too complicated, and has very different concepts comparing with other VCS.
- SVN keeps too large cache file in local workspace, actually at least as large as the current workspace content.

Comment: PlasitcSCM was the first thing that I thought of, they are very heavily biased towards multimedia developers. Can you tell us what the problems were? Did you contact them? They are very friendly and helpful (and very active on their own forums).